# How change the keycloak port in docker (AWS ECS)

Tags: dockerfile, keycloak, amazon-ecs

how i a can change the listening http port of keycloak
i tried with env variable with KEYCLOAK_HTTP_PORT but it doesnt work ,
i want to run keycloak in aws ECS with different port of 8080 like 8081 instead
Thanks in advance , really

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass this parameter on the command:

-Djboss.http.port=80